# WinRT : The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c++-winrt

I know when this error information comes up. In c++/cx it used to work. But in c++/winrt it's a marshaling problem.

I am trying to create some timers from my init method.

Init Method :

```
void App::InitAsync()
{
    concurrency::create_task([this]
        {
            //Do my stuffs
        }).then([this](concurrency::task<void> task)
            {
                try
                {
                    task.get();
                }
                catch (const std::exception& /*e*/)
                {
                }
                m_timer = CreateAndStartDispatcherTimer(500ms, &App::OnTimerTick);

            }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_default());
}
```

The Timer creation method:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer App::CreateAndStartDispatcherTimer(std::chrono::milliseconds interval, void(App::* onTick)(IInspectable sender, IInspectable e))
{
    auto timer{ DispatcherTimer() }; // the exception is thrown from here
    timer.Tick(EventHandler<IInspectable>(this, onTick));
    timer.Interval(interval);
    timer.Start();
    return timer;
}
```

Please suggest how can I make it work. For reproduction i uploaded the solution [here](https://github.com/sohel364/WinrtTestProject).

Answer (score 1):

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread

This exception means your function touches the app's UI and then it needs to run on the UI's dispatcher thread. So you can co_await the **winrt::resume_foreground** function to switch to a specific foreground thread. For example:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h>

{
    ......
    CreateAndStartDispatcherTimer(yourInterval);
}

Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction winrt::AsyncAppWinrt::implementation::App::CreateAndStartDispatcherTimer(std::chrono::milliseconds interval)
{
    co_await winrt::resume_foreground(Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView().CoreWindow().Dispatcher());

    m_timer = Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer();
    m_timer.Interval(interval);
    auto registrationtoken = m_timer.Tick({ this, &App::OnTick });
    m_timer.Start();
}
```

For more details about this, you can refer to this document: [More advanced concurrency and asynchrony with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind)

Comment: with co_await I faced some more issues. But it works with ..Dispatcher().RunAsync. I am not sure if this is the proper way.

Comment: void App::CreateAndStartDispatcherTimer(Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer& timer, std::chrono::milliseconds interval, void(App::* onTick)(IInspectable sender, IInspectable e))
{
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView().CoreWindow().Dispatcher().RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Low, [&]() {
        timer = DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick(EventHandler<IInspectable>(this, &App::OnTimerTick));
        timer.Interval(500ms);
        timer.Start();
        return timer;
        });
}

Comment: The implementation of winrt::resume_foreground calls CoreDispatcher.RunAsync on that dispatcher object to execute the work that comes after it in the coroutine. So winrt::resume_foreground and ..Dispatcher().RunAsync functions are equivalent, you can also use ..Dispatcher().RunAsync to switch to foreground thread.